# Livewire: problem whit display data and form

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I have problem with display data and form on one page.
Display data from database disappear after write in textarea any word. The same problem ist when i click on submit. In debugger is only data from first query, from second is cleared.
I try with one query (second), but it's the same.

My example code

- route web:

  ```
   Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/tickets/show/{slug}', Tickets\Show::class)->name('tickets.show');
  ```

Livewire:

```
public $ticket;
public $slug;
public $posts;
public $content_post;
public  $ticket_id;

public function mount($slug){
    $this->ticket = Tickets::where('tickets.id','=', $slug)->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tickets.user_id')
        ->select('users.email','users.phone','users.username','users.first_name','users.last_name','tickets.user_id','tickets.created_at',
            'tickets.id', 'tickets.subject','tickets.status_id','tickets.admin_id')->first();
    $this->posts = TicketsPost::where('tickets_posts.ticket_id','=', $slug)->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tickets_posts.user_id')
        ->select('users.email','users.username','users.first_name','users.last_name','tickets_posts.user_id','tickets_posts.created_at',
            'tickets_posts.ticket_id','tickets_posts.post')->get();
}
public function addPost()
{

    $this->validate([
        'content_post' => 'required'
    ]);
    $user_id = Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier();

  
        TicketsPost::create([
            'ticket_id' => $this->ticket_id,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'post' => $this->content_post,
        ]);
   


}
public function render()
{

    return view('livewire.tickets.show');
}
```

- View:

  ```
    <p >#{{$ticket->id}}</p>
                        <p >{{$ticket->subject}}</p>

                    @foreach($posts as $post)

                                    <p >{{$post->first_name}}  {{$post->last_name}}</p>
                                    <p >{{ date('d.m.Y H:i',strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</p>
                                <p > {{$post->post}}</p>
                    @endforeach


                        <form  >
                            <input type="hidden" name="ticket_id" value="2"  wire:model="ticket_id">
                            <textarea  name="content_post"
                                      class=""
                                      rows="5" required="" placeholder="Treść wiadomości" wire:model="content_post"></textarea>
                                    @error('content_post') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                                    <button wire:click.prevent="addPost()" type="submit" class="">
                                        <span id="btn_text" class="ml-2">Dodaj</span>
                                    </button>
                        </form>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In Livewire, make sure your component has a single-level root element only.
And, don't forget to add `wire:key` in your element inside every loop in a blade.

Your loop should be as;

```
@foreach($posts as $key => $post)
<div wire:key="{{'post'.$key}}">
<p>{{$post->first_name}} {{$post->last_name}}</p>
 <p >{{ date('d.m.Y H:i',strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</p>
<p > {{$post->post}}</p>
</div>
@endforeach
```